# Blocking wayback machine via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Found following piece on one of stacks that is supposed to block waybackmachine's crawler.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (archive.org_bot) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

I have also read that "RewriteEngine On" is supposed to be used only once in the file. Original htaccess looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and with my edits, it now looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (archive.org_bot) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I decided to test it. Created account on WBM, took a snap shot and it worked. So, apparently, the redirect didn't work. Not sure, what exactly did I do wrong?

Comment: You question is somewhat confusing: "... and it worked. So, ... redirect didn't work." Could you be more specific what did and what did not work?

Comment: An easier approach might be to block the agent through `/robots.txt`. See http://www.robotstxt.org/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Answer (score 0):

Add this bad bots block rule (with archive.org bot):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (360Spider|acapbot|acoonbot|ahrefs|alexibot|archive.org|asterias|attackbot|backdorbot|becomebot|binlar|blackwidow|blekkobot|blexbot|blowfish|bullseye|bunnys|butterfly|careerbot|casper|checkpriv|cheesebot|cherrypick|chinaclaw|choppy|clshttp|cmsworld|copernic|copyrightcheck|cosmos|crescent|cy_cho|datacha|demon|diavol|discobot|dittospyder|dotbot|dotnetdotcom|dumbot|emailcollector|emailsiphon|emailwolf|exabot|extract|eyenetie|feedfinder|flaming|flashget|flicky|foobot|g00g1e|getright|gigabot|go-ahead-got|gozilla|grabnet|grafula|harvest|heritrix|httrack|icarus6j|jetbot|jetcar|jikespider|kmccrew|leechftp|libweb|linkextractor|linkscan|linkwalker|loader|miner|mj12bot|majestic|mechanize|morfeus|moveoverbot|netmechanic|netspider|nicerspro|nikto|ninja|nutch|octopus|pagegrabber|planetwork|postrank|proximic|purebot|pycurl|python|queryn|queryseeker|radian6|radiation|realdownload|rogerbot|scooter|seekerspider|semalt|seznambot|siclab|sindice|sistrix|sitebot|siteexplorer|sitesnagger|skygrid|smartdownload|snoopy|sosospider|spankbot|spbot|sqlmap|stackrambler|stripper|sucker|surftbot|sux0r|suzukacz|suzuran|takeout|teleport|telesoft|true_robots|turingos|turnit|vampire|vikspider|voideye|webleacher|webreaper|webstripper|webvac|webviewer|webwhacker|winhttp|wwwoffle|woxbot|xaldon|xxxyy|yamanalab|yioopbot|youda|zeus|zmeu|zune|zyborg) [NC]    
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

Comment: do i need to add new IfModule, or do i put it in the same one?

Comment: Better is add new one before line with # BEGIN WordPress.  After that wordpress will not been able to overwrite changes in this rule.